# Why aren't passing V64 chords in minor notated with a raised 6 in figured bass?

Tags: figured-bass

If all accidentals are supposed to be notated in the figures why do passing 64 chords only appear with 64 and no slash or sharp symbol next to the 6. The 6 in a passing 64 chord is the leading tone which should have an accidental in minor.

Answer (score 2):

You're exactly right: this accidental on the sixth *should* be indicated.

If the example in question also includes Roman numerals, the accidental may have been viewed as redundant: since the V is major, then by default we must raise that sixth to make the dominant chord major. In other words, the use of the leading tone is implied by the major dominant, so adding it in the figures is overkill. It's not technically correct from a figured-bass standpoint, but that's the logic.

Comment: On the other side it would be necessary to make a natural or a flat to make clear if it is a minor chord ....